# I want to fetch data date-wise from table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to fetch data date-wise from a table.

This is the table structure;

```
 String TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+DBContract.TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS+"("
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_VISITOR_USER_ID+" INTEGER,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_MEET_TO+" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_VISIT_DATE+" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_ENTRY_TIME +" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_EXIT_DATE_TIME +" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_PURPOSE +" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_STATUS +" TEXT,"
                +DBContract.VISIT_DETAILS_ITEM_CARRIED +" TEXT"+
                ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to fetch data between 2 dates(timestamp).

@Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_VISIT_DETAILS WHERE date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2")
List getDataBetweenInterval(long date1, long date2);